# Unable to grab/move keyframes in Grease Pencil Dope Sheet

Tags: animation, transforms, keyframes, grease-pencil, 2d

I'm new to Blender and currently working in the 2D Animation workspace. It's likely that I accidentally hit a hotkey that would restrict me from doing so, but for whatever reason, I am unable to grab and move keyframes in the Dope Sheet on a particular save file.

When I start a new Blender project, it works just fine, but I've already made too much progress in this file to start over. I am able to duplicate keyframes and slide them around the timeline, so I've been working around it by doing that and deleting the keyframes in their previous position. As you can imagine, it's not very efficient.

Comment: Are you in edit mode? Are you working with an appended/linked model? Make sure you aren't in local mode by tapping /

Comment: Found this on Blender's dev site: https://developer.blender.org/T72717
Seems like a similar issue...

Comment: Thank you. I did see that issue you linked but it doesn't seem to be quite the same. It doesn't appear to make a difference what mode I'm in—edit, object, or draw mode are all the same result—I can neither use 'G' to grab and move the keyframes, nor can I click and drag them in the timeline.

Comment: And forgive me, I'm not sure what you mean by an appended/linked model. Can you clarify? I did confirm that i'm not in local mode as well.

Comment: (Appending/linking is when you reference data from another .blend file to use in your current file.)

Based off what you have said thus far, can you upload your .blend file? (Use https://blend-exchange.com) This way I can try to troubleshoot the issue better on my end.

Comment: Here it is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DZvG9q3AoHV_bTT_KJccBp_C3umOkLbw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I just selected everything, copied it, and pasted it into a new file. It worked there, and all your stuff carried over too. No idea what happened, though.

Comment: Yup, that seemed to fix it haha. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! I'll post my comment as an answer so you can solve this!

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, and turns out I had enabled "Proportional editing" on the dope sheet by accident. Hope this helps future googlers.
[image: Location of propotional editing button]

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what happened, but I just selected everything, copied it, and pasted it into a new file. It worked there, and all your stuff carried over too.